# Low Variables, Matrix and Playa

Tags: matrix, playa, low-variables

I've got a Low Variables group setup called 'Widget sources'.

Inside this group I have 6 Low Variables, all Playa fieldtypes.

I've got some channel entries selected so there are relationship in the system...

I have a Matrix field type setup in a Channel field group which points to my Low Variable group. Multiple selections set to yes.

When I try to publish a new entry in my channel, and create a new Matrix row, my Low variable field type column is blank?

Should I be able to select something here?

What am I doing wrong?

See screenshots attached.

Thanks

Sean

Screenshots:

http://cl.ly/TphQ

http://cl.ly/TpNX

http://cl.ly/TqMd

Comment: What are the properties of those LVs? Make sure there not hidden and early parsing is turned off.

Comment: Cool. I'll add it as an answer. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll quote [the docs](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-variables/docs/fieldtype) here:

> Please note that only *non-hidden* and variables with *early parsing disabled* show up in the variable list in the Publish Form.

So, make sure the vars you want to select are not hidden and have early parsing disabled.